# Configure https agent to allow only TLS1.2 for outgoing requests

Tags: node.js, https, tls1.2

I'm making HTTPS connections from a node app, using a client certificate:

```
var options = { 
    hostname: 'https://my-server.com', 
    port: 443, 
    path: '/', 
    method: 'GET', 
    key: fs.readFileSync('client1-key.pem'), 
    cert: fs.readFileSync('client1-crt.pem'), 
    ca: fs.readFileSync('ca-crt.pem') }; 

var req = https.request(options, res => { 
    [...]
});
```

Everything is working fine, however I want to add code to ensure only TLS 1.2 connections are allowed. I cannot find any way to configure this in the [https.agent](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent) options, or elsewhere. Is it possible to configure this, or do I have to make a connection and then [query the protocol](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tlssocket_getprotocol) version, with something like:

`res.socket.getProtocol() === 'TLSv1.2'`

and abort the connection if the protocol is not satisfactory?

Comment: alternatively you can use nginx as a reverse proxy to terminate your TLS traffic so shielding nodejs from having to deal with https yet communicate with outside world via https ...  removing the complexity of asking nodejs to handle any TLS related matters entirely ... nginx is config driven, no need to code security logic ... nginx also handles WebSockets

Comment: Thus is for outgoing requests.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use a specific TLS version with \`node-fetch\` like TLS v1.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77207601/how-do-i-use-a-specific-tls-version-with-node-fetch-like-tls-v1-2)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First I found the docs on making [HTTPS requests](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback). It mentions that you can pass additional options to `tls.connect()` which includes something called `secureProtocol`. Digging into [`tls.connect()`](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_connect_options_callback), I found the `secureContext` option which mentions [`tls.createSecureContext()`](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createsecurecontext_options). And there it finally mentions `secureProtocol` which can be specified with a string from [an OpenSSL page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/ssl/SSL.html#DEALING-WITH-PROTOCOL-METHODS). I picked a string that looked reasonable (`TLSv1_2_method`) and passed the `secureProtocol` option directly into `https.request`.

This prints `SSL Version: TLS 1.2` with the given `secureProtocol` and `SSL Version: TLS 1.1` with `secureProtocol: "TLSv1_1_method"`. The error handler at the end will get called if a connection cannot be established with the given TLS version.

```
var https = require('https')

var options = {
    hostname: 'www.howsmyssl.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/a/check',
    method: 'GET',
    secureProtocol: "TLSv1_2_method"
}

https.request(options, res => {
  let body = ''
  res.on('data', d => body += d)
  res.on('end', () => {
    data = JSON.parse(body)
    console.log('SSL Version: ' + data.tls_version)
  })
}).on('error', err => {
  // This gets called if a connection cannot be established.
  console.warn(err)
}).end()
```

Comment: Brilliant answer, this worked great. Really helpful, thanks!

Comment: adding the test for success:  openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -tls1 - should fail   openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -tls1_2 should not

Comment: @supersam654 the link is openssl link is broken. Possibly, the new link is http://openssl.cs.utah.edu/docs/ssl/ssl.html#dealing_with_protocol_methods

Comment: @coding_idiot thanks for letting me know. I did a bit of spelunking and found the correct link on openssl.org. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44635449/2

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this with a HTTPs agent?

Comment: What's the default value node uses?

Comment: I still don't understand why axios and fetch does not support tlsv.12 out of box. :sad

Answer (score 9):

Just an update about this solution, a couple of years have passed and some things have changed.

Node docs now recommends to use `minVersion` and `maxVersion` instead `secureProtocol` since this last option has become the legacy mechanism to select the TLS protocol version, so you can get the same result by using `minVersion: "TLSv1.2"`:

```js
var https = require('https')

var options = {
    hostname: 'www.howsmyssl.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/a/check',
    method: 'GET',
    minVersion: "TLSv1.2",
    maxVersion: "TLSv1.2"
}
...
```

References: [Node docs: tls_tls_createsecurecontext_options](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createsecurecontext_options)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tls` library:

```
const tls = require('tls');

tls.DEFAULT_MIN_VERSION = 'TLSv1.2';
```